# Mysql relationship one-many get data with more where clause

Tags: php, mysql, database, relationship, one-to-many

I have 2 table in my mysql database

1 is for registry all personal information with ID autoincrement 
2 is for some attribute with value and have ID_Anagrafica = ID

My question is: If i want to search in first table only the registry with some attribute value on the second table, how can i do this?

example:

First registry table:
[image]

Second table for attribute with value:

[image]

`ID_Anagrafica` matches with `ID` in `registry`

There is a query that return ID with where clause on second table:

```
SELECT *
FROM "first table"
WHERE "secondTable".valore = "value"
AND "secondTable".valore = "value";
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be one way... The values for the in and the value for the count could be variables passed in however, as you will always know what values you're passing in and how many there are...

```
SELECT * 
FROM First A
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID_anafrafica 
            FROM Second
            WHERE Valore in ('value1','Value2')
            Group by ID_anafrafica 
            having count(ID_Anafrafica) = 2) B
 on A.ID  = B.ID_anafrafica
```

What I don't like about this is you're not keying off of ID_Attributo and I think you should be if you're looking for the Valore of the attribute

This should scales better in performance and maintainability than adding additional joins for each element.

Comment: I try your query like this but i get error: table first doesn't exist

SELECT * FROM FIRST Anagrafica INNER JOIN (SELECT ID_Anagrafica FROM Dati_Attributi WHERE Valore IN ('11', '14') GROUP BY ID_Anagrafica HAVING COUNT (ID_Anagrafica) = 2) Dati_Attributi ON Anagrafica.ID = Dati_Attributi.ID_Anagrafica;

Comment: You have to substitute 'First' and 'Second' for your respective table names.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) for that.

```
SELECT a.* FROM "first table" AS a <br>
JOIN "second table" AS b ON a.ID = b.ID_Anagrafica <br>
WHERE b.valore = "value" <br>
GROUP BY a.ID;
```

Comment: The problem here is that he's looking for two criteria and since it's a one to many there will be two records in the second table, and the where clause can't match both.  This is correct on the surface, but it's missing a key point.

Comment: Can't he just use conditional "AND"s in the WHERE clause to match those criteria?

Comment: You can use GROUP BY in that case

Comment: Need to join another one "second table" to search second valore value.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply.
How can i do tfor add another second join for second value. 
I have many attribute must match with second table

For example i want to know all registry.ID that match with ID_Attributo = 16 AND Valore = 'Fluente' AND ID_Attributo = 15 AND Valore = 'Fluente'